# Best tool for scheduling tasks at intervals?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I have a service that I'm writing in Python that allows users to schedule a task to happen at different intervals.  Examples of tasks would be:

- Task A: do a status check for every 10 seconds
- Task B: do a status check for every 3 seconds
- Task C: do a status check for every 15 seconds

The tasks should run independently of each other.  I also want to make sure that `Task A` can't run again until it's previous attempt is complete.  Remember that the number of tasks is dynamic, and so in the interval at which they run.

I've looked at RabbitMQ, but am having a hard time deciding if it's capable of this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using celery recently to do what you are trying to achieve. With celery you can create tasks which are essentially functions that you are distributed to a task queue. You can also make celery tasks run periodically, whether that means every x seconds or a more crontab style approach.

Look for periodic tasks in the celery documentation to see if it suits what you are trying to do. Celery uses rabbitmq or redis (primarily). Each task runs in its own separated thread from the main program.

Answer (score 1):

You should setup a few task queues, one for each type of task. Then, when you have a new task to do, just put it in the queue. This ensures that they happen serially, in-order, and at a consistent interval of your choosing.

Consider [Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS)](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/details/) or [Amazon Simple Workflow Service](https://aws.amazon.com/swf/details/) instead of maintaining your own [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html)/[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) instance(s).

See info about [using Python boto3 library with SQS](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/sqs_tut.html).